# accessing private member in public const method

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, stl

I have the following C++ class and methods. I am attempting to accessing the private member "outgoing" from within the const function `numOutgoing()`.  I am confused about the behavior for lines 127-128 vs 129-130.

Line 129: Making a copy, which can be modified later, const function does not care
Line 130: Getting a reference, but vec is defined as const, so all good.

Line 127: I assumed a copy is being made, but I get a compiler error
Line 128: Same compiler error.

```
 90 class Graph
 91 {
 92         map<int, vector<int> > outgoing;
 93
 95   public:
 96         Graph(const vector<int> &starts, const vector<int> &ends);
 97         int numOutgoing(const int nodeID) const;
 99 };
100
120
121 int
122 Graph::numOutgoing(const int nodeID) const
123 {
124         if (outgoing.find(nodeID) == outgoing.end()) {
125                 throw invalid_argument("Invalid node Id");
126         }
127         // vector<int> vec = outgoing[nodeID];
128         // const vector<int> &vec = outgoing[nodeID];
129         vector<int> vec = outgoing.at(nodeID);
130         // const vector<int> &vec = outgoing.at(nodeID);
131
132         return vec.size();
133 }
```

I am trying to understand why Line 127 / 128 gives me the following compilation error:

```
./templ.cc:128:42: error: passing 'const std::map<int, std::vector<int> >' as 'this' argument of 'std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = int; _Tp = std::vector<int>; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::vector<int> > >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = std::vector<int>; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = int]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

Following are the prototypes for operator[] and at methods in the "map" class.

```
      mapped_type& operator[] (const key_type& k);  <======
      mapped_type& operator[] (key_type&& k);

      mapped_type& at (const key_type& k);
const mapped_type& at (const key_type& k) const;
```

Would really appreciate it if someone can help me understand the compilation error.  Could the issue be that `operator[]` does not return a `const` type?  If so, then `operator[]` and `at` are not equivalent, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the method

```
int Graph::numOutgoing(const int nodeID) const
```

is `const`, while `operator[]` is not const. This is because of a design decision: If one tries to access a key that does not exist with `operator[]`, then it creates it, thus modifying the `std::map`.

To solve your problem, use `map<int, vector<int> >::const_iterator result = outgoing.find(nodeID);` Then, if it's not at `end()`, you can simply access the key with `result->first` and the value with `result->second`.

Comment: If he can use C++11, the `std::map::at()` function would work as well, but it with throw if the item is not found, so you would need a try-catch block.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that as your `numOutgoing` function is const, so it can only call const functions on the class members.  In this case only `const mapped_type& at (const key_type& k) const;` is valid.

You could also keep the `const_iterator` from `outgoing.find(nodeID)` and dereference that to get const access to your child vector.

Answer (score 2):

> Would really appreciate it if someone can help me understand the compilation error. Could the issue be that "operator[]" does not return a "const" type? If so, then "operator[]" and "at" are not equivalent, right?

Yes, `operator[]` and `at` are not equivalent at all.

`at` will only always return a value therefore it can be `const`. If no such element exists, an exception of type `std::out_of_range` is thrown.

`operator[]` on the other hand will never complain if no elements exists as it will try to create a new one. This behavior is chosen so that:

```
std::map<int, int> x;
x[0] = 1;
```

is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is operator [] which is nonconst. A caller could modify map contents with non-const reference it returns, so this operator is not marked const.